# Can I choose when animation in animated dupli-groups starts?

Tags: animation, dupli-groups

I'd like to use some sort of re-usable animations (think little animated effects, simple but a lot of them), that I can play during my main animation, without creating multiple actions, or having multiple nla blocks. I was thinking that animated dupli-groups would be ideal. But can I choose when animation in animated dupli-groups starts? If not, then this way clearly won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Currently this isn't supported**

This used to be supported (in 2.49), using the *Time Offset* field on the empty object instancing the dupli-group.

However support for this is planned. One of the goals for having an improved dependency graph (currently in development), is to have local time for group instances.